# How can I visualize the relationship (distance metrics) between multiple vectors?

Tags: python, vector, scipy, euclidean-distance

I want to calculate the distance between multiple (approx. six) vectors in Python and subsequently I want to visualize the results since the numbers alone do not adequately represent the general context.

For the first step, I plan to use spatial distance measures from scipy (e.g. euclidian).

However, I am not sure how to visualize the relationship/distances between all vectors.
Is there any suitable Python module?
Or is there any easier solution for step one and two together?

Edit:

Each vector consists of a distribution over 50 variables and adds up to 100 %.
So the dimension is 50 x 1 for each of the six vectors.

An easier example:
V1: (0.2 0.4 0.4)
V2: (0.1 0.7 0.2)
V3: (0.5 0.1 0.4) ...

Now I want to compute the distance between those vectors and visualize all the distances to see the overall relationship between all vectors.

Comment: matplotlib could be useful

Comment: what shape are your vectors?

Comment: Each vector consists of a distribution over 50 variables and adds up to 100 %.
So the dimension is 50 x 1 for each of the six vectors.

An easier example:
V1:  (0.2 0.4 0.4)
V2:  (0.1 0.7 0.2)
V3:  (0.5 0.1 0.4)
...

Now I want to compute the distance between those vectors and visualize all the distances to see the overall relationship between all vectors.